# Types of PRFs and its applications

Tags: pseudo-random-function, io

I was learning about iO from [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/454.pdf)
when I noticed the different new types of PRFs. I wanted a clear understanding of the following.

1. What are Puncturable PRF (PPRF)? Why is it defined in the way it is? Applications?
2. What are Statistically Injective PPRFs and their need?
3. What are Extracting PPRF and its applications?

Please Explain the need of introducing the following types and the additional advantage it provides in the design compared to normal PRFs.

Comment: can you provide some definitions of these things? what context did you see them in? links to papers other documents?

Comment: Paper reference: https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/454.pdf

Comment: ok, added to main text of question

Comment: Why are they defined that way? Because that's the only way these authors found to achieve the results they wanted. Presumably normal PRFs did not suffice or they would have used them. What are the applications? The entire purpose of this paper is to describe their applications. In particular, the first 5-6 pages do a great job at giving a high-level overview of how these PRF variants are used. I'm not sure what additional value we can add here at Crypto.SE -- you will probably have to ask a much more specific question.